# How do you detect a pattern match when comparing two unique strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, automaton, rabin-karp

I'm looking for a solution to the following string pattern matching problem.

You've got a function that takes two arguments: pattern, and input - both are strings.

Let's say `pattern: aabbaa` and `input: catcatdogdogcatcat`

These specific arguments would be considered a match because there is a pattern in the characters of `input`, and that pattern matches the pattern of words in `pattern`

Return a `boolean` to indicate where or not there is a match.
The examples given above would return `1`.

```
function (pattern, input) {
  // patterns within the input string are elucidated from input
  // those patterns are checked against the pattern
  return boolean
}
```

Comment: What's the criteria here? The pattern can be `aabc` for your example.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote 'n dash :)

Comment: @st0le I'll rework the question - `aabc` would not be the right pattern

Comment: Still not a good question on stack

Comment: Then why does it have -2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generalized problem "Find the patterns for a given string" is a lot harder to solve, because a string can conform to multiple patterns. For example,

```
catcatdogcat
```

Conforms to many patterns. Here's a non-exhaustive list:

```
aaba           cat cat dog cat
a              catcatdogcat
ab             catcat dogcat
abcabcefgabc   c a t c a t d o g c a t
ababcab        ca t ca t dog ca t
```

So I don't think the approach of "find all patterns, then see if the proposed pattern is among them" will work.

That implies that we probably want to use the proposed pattern as a guideline to try to break the string down, but I'm not completely sure how that would look either.

In the specific case when the pattern starts and ends with the same substring (such as in `aaba`), I suppose you could start from the beginning and ending of the string, consuming one character at a time until you get a match:

```
catcatdogcat
CatcatdogcaT
CAtcatdogcAT
CATcatdogCAT <-- Substring "CAT" is a candidate for "a". Check if that pattern matches.
```

But the more general case is harder again. A similar approach can be taken, though, such as trying every string to see if it conforms to the pattern, with backtracking:

```
catcatdogcat
Catcatdogcat <-- The string isn't "CCsomethingC", so a != "C"
CAtcatdogcat <-- the string isn't "CACAsomethingCA", so a != "CA"
CATcatdogcat <-- the string is "CATCATsomethingCAT", so a = "CAT" is a candidate.
```

Once you find a candidate, you can remove it from the string and from the pattern string, reducing the next step to comparing `dog` against the pattern `b`. In pseudocode,

```
checkpattern(pattern, string) :=
  if (pattern has just one letter) 
    return true
  if (pattern has more than one letter, but it's one character repeated)
    return whether the string repeats that way
  for (each substring from the start of the string of length x=[0..])
    does the string match this candidate substring following the pattern?
    if (yes)
      if (checkpattern(pattern - letter, string - substring))
        return true
      else
        continue
    if (no)
      continue
  return false
```

I think that would work. Obviously there are a lot of details to this pseudocode, and it's not very efficient, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful insight. I'll give this a try this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Create a nested loop to check.

```
int i =0;
char tester [] = "xyzfffasdfsadf";
bool checker = false;
while (tester[i] != '\0')
{
    if (tester [i] == 'x')
    {
        i++;
       if (tester[i] == 'y')
       {
          i++;
          if (tester[i] == 'z')
          {
             checker = true;
          }
       }
   }else {
    i++;
   }
}
if(checker == true){
cout << "Pattern exist";
}
```

This is a simple way in c++ or java to do it, I would feel so. the numbers of nested loops would be the number of characters to check for if the pattern exists. you could also include a second counter, in the last loop to increment to count the number of times the pattern occurs.

Comment: Appreciate the idea. but the solution needs to able to handle any string, not just strings containing x, y, and z. Also, this solution could be more efficient.

Comment: The solution, in which the x,y,z can be replaced. The x, y, z is a representation of the pattern in which you are looking to detect. So you could actually have multiple separate counters to detect multiple patterns and increment the counter if the pattern is identified. 

Yes, i would agree that the solution could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how i did it

```
def check_pattern(s1,s2):
    i=j=97
    p1=p2=""

    for index1,l1 in enumerate(s1):
        if l1 not in s1[0:index1]:
            p1+=chr(i)
            i+=1
        else:
            p1+= chr(97+s1.index(l1))

    
    for index2,l2 in enumerate(s2):
        if l2 not in s2[0:index2]:
            p2+=chr(j)
            j+=1
        else:
            p2+= chr(97+s2.index(l2))

    if p1==p2:
        return True
    else:
        return False

z=check_pattern("aab","xxz")
print(z)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

Hey here is a very simple function that can be used for pattern matching:

```
    def check_string(str1,str2):
    
        if(len(str1)!=len(str2)):
            return False
        else:
            for i in range(len(str1)):
                for I in range(i+1,len(str1)):
                    if str1[I] == str1[i]:
                        indx1=I
                for J in range(i+1,len(str2)):
                    if str2[J] == str2[i]:
                        indx2=J
                if(indx1!=indx2):
                    return False
        return True
    
   str1 = "catcatcatdogcat" #you can insert any string say abc,xyz  
                            #i used this example
   str2 = "tietietiefortie"
   result = check_string(str1, str2)
   print(result)
```

explanation 1:the two strings must be of the same length

explanation 2: we can iterate over the length of either of string since its same

explanation 3: we now must check the subsequent letters after first letter in string 1 thats why the range starts from i+1

explanation 4: we now check if the letter appears elsewhere in the string and if yes we store this index in indx1

explanation 5: we do the same for the second string as well

explanation 6: we now check if the indexes are same for both the strings this is to check whether the occurrences of the letters are in the same position, if false return False

explanation 7: we return True in the end after we have traversed the entire string to avoid returning True after first instance

This code has been written in python .I hope this helps :)

**Please note that I have used only strings for solving this problem as required by the question in Educative Course Certification exam.**